# Android Studio java ssl socket connection

Tags: android-studio, сокет, ssl, connection

Я использую для подключения к ssl socket следующую команду:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.13:1183 -cert client.pem -key client.key
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как все это реализовать в приложении Android Studio на java...? 
Или где можно почитать об этом.

Comment: А, Вам нужно обязательно через сокет?

Comment: Обязательно. Это защищенное соединение по собственному протоколу.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, в Android SDK есть абстрактный класс SSLSOcket (подробности [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket)).

Инициализация осуществляется через фабрику:

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("host", port);
```

С предварительной настройкой:

```
KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore); //open inputstream for keystore file in "raw" folder
trusted.load(in, "passw".toCharArray());                                 //load the keystore from file (using password specified when certificate was imported into keystore)       
in.close();                                                              //close inputstream 
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(trusted, "passw".toCharArray());
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");               //configure SSL Context to use TLS v1.2 
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(),null,null);
SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
```

Пример взят [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58052483/ssl-tls-connection-from-android-to-a-custom-socket-server). Там же дополнительные пояснения (правда на английском).

После получения защищённого сокета можно обмениваться данными по Вашему протоколу.

Comment: Да. Я уже использую это. Проблема, похоже, в моем непонимании как объеденить в едином хранилище ключей **keystore.bks** (насколько я понял,  для Android приложений не "JKS", а "BKS")  _client.pem_ & _client.key_ ... Команда применяемая для создания  **keystore.bks**: 'keytool -importcert -file client.pem -keystore keystore.bks -storetype BKS -alias "alias" -storepass passw' создает **keystore.bks** c _client.pem_ ...  Но, что делать c _client.key_  я не понимаю.

Comment: Я нашел в документации, что _client.pem_ & _client.key_ нужно объеденить в единый пакет формата pkcs12.
После чего уже создавать keystore.bks на основе этого файла (пакет формата pkcs12).

Comment: Я использую следующую последовательность действий по объединению _client.pem_ & _client.key_ в единый формат **pkcs12** (инструменты openssl keytool):

Comment: 1. openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.pem -inkey client.key -certfile root.pem -out mystore.p12 // результат **mystore.p12**

Comment: 2. keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mystore.p12 -srcstorepass qwerty -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore mystore.bks -deststorepass qwerty -deststoretype bks -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath /Users/alexandergaranin/Desktop/pbfgroup/ssl/sertsample/bcprov-jdk15on-164.jar // результат **mystore.bks**

Comment: 3. Далее импортируем mystore.bks в Android Studio в assets. И загружаем через InputStream:
 'InputStream in = getResources().getAssets().open("mystore.bks");'

Comment: 4. Но на попытке "рукопожатия":
 'sslsocket.startHandshake();'
 получаю ошибку "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."